# mp3 is treated like video by tomcat (spring boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I have an mp3 inside the war created by spring boot,

and when I try to use it with

```
<source src="/tomcat/soundz/tik.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
```

it doesn't work,

if I go to the path on the server:

```
http://somedomain.org/tomcat/soundz/tik.mp3
```

The mp3 is shown as video in stead of audio element, i.e.:

If I open the file locally with firefox/chrome it is displayed as audio (just a play button):
[image]

(and I can play the mp3)

but if I browse to it on the server it appears as a video:

[image: Video display]

And you cannot play it...

It used to work but suddenly it stopped working...

the mp3 is inside the:

```
projectname\src\main\resources\static\soundz
```

Directory inside eclipse,

I didn't find anything useful on the internet :(

Thanks for pointers/tips or - even better - a solution :-D

S.

**edit:** these are the headers (still not helping...)

```
GET /tomcat/soundz/tik.mp3 HTTP/1.1
Host: myhost:443
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
DNT: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36

HTTP/1.1 200
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 14888
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
Date: Tue, 25 Feb 2020 13:42:53 GMT
Last-Modified: Sun, 23 Feb 2020 11:43:51 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
```

**edit2:**

Locally there are no headers.

Comment: Open the developer console (F12 on chrome), and look at the headers that the server is returning. Compare the headers between local and remote server.

Comment: @Kayaman: locally there are no headers and the headers on the server seem to indicate they are sound: "audio/mpeg"...